# SHOW FULL COLUMN in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am newbie in cakephp, and I am confused about SHOW FULL COLUMN query
I've set debug leel into 2, and I clicked on one page, its show 88 queries (even the data is NULL)
Here the queries:

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `item_purchase_returns`      10  10  2

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `purchases`      20  20  2

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `outcomes`       13  13  1

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `transaction_categories`     7   7   96

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `incomes`        16  16  2

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `last_receivables`       14  14  1

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `last_funds`     7   7   1
...
etc

My question is why does cakePHP do this?
Does those queries are usefull? 
Is cakePHP calls those queries on each page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

CakePHP calls those queries in order to build it's internal model of your database tables.  It does call them quite often in development mode (the cache is flushed every 10 seconds) in case you make changes to your database, but if the debug level is set to production (0), it will assume you aren't making any database changes and only flush the cache every 99 years (essentially never).  Thus, if you wish to make changes to the database of an app in production, you either have to delete your cached models in `/app/tmp/` or temporarily change to development mode.